# What are good books to study geometry for the IMO

Tags: geometry, contest-math, book-recommendation

I am looking to compete in the IMO, or at least in some other mathematical competitions. I read online that geometry is an important topic in many competitions, and so I'm looking for a book to self study.However most stuff I found so far was too basic (pythagorean theorem...) and so I'm interested in anything that covers more advanced topics or that has a lot of challenging practise problems.

Comment: To compete in the IMO you need to first qualify for the team of your country.  Ok, assuming that :-) Of course, you should have a full command of basic Euclidean geometry (as covered in *Elementa*). But then you should start working out past contest problems. This is the best way to prepare for a contest (two time IMO bronze medalist here). Don't dive into the deep end without due training. Of course, a book filled with training problems is a good idea, but you also need patience. Good luck.

Comment: Evan Chen's EGMO revolutionzed the geometry section from what I heard. The exam became more difficult after the book was written.

Comment: Your country’s olympiad preparation probably has some useful material online – and you’ll want to get in touch with them anyway. Arthur Engel’s *Problem-Solving Strategies* is worth a read but I found the geometry section not quite attuned to the current “spirit” of the problems.

Comment: @Aphelli That is putting it mildly. It's a great book, but its geometry chapter falls short of the level of most of the rest of the book. I participated in the IMO, and much of the geometry we got during our training I later found back in Coxeter's *Introduction to geometry*, the first few chapter to be precise. So that might be a place to look.